# Expand grid (or power set) of a data table with new columns in R

Tags: r, matrix, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

I have a data table that I have carefully constructed (toy example provided below):

```
  library(data.table)
     Vmat1 = data.table(expand.grid(c(list(d = 1:2, w = 1:(3)))))

> Vmat1
   d w
1: 1 1
2: 2 1
3: 1 2
4: 2 2
5: 1 3
6: 2 3
```

I want to take the power set in the following sense.  For every column of Vmat, I want to create a new a column of the same name with the suffix "prime".   Then I want to enumerate the power set such that for every original row in the original data, there is a new row of all possibilities (not relevant to the problem, but you might be able to imagine correctly I am trying to work with state transitions in a Markov chain)

This would give the following output:

```
    d w dprime wprime
 1: 1 1      1      1
 2: 2 1      1      1
 3: 1 2      1      1
 4: 2 2      1      1
 5: 1 3      1      1
 6: 2 3      1      1
 7: 1 1      2      1
 8: 2 1      2      1
 9: 1 2      2      1
10: 2 2      2      1
11: 1 3      2      1
12: 2 3      2      1
13: 1 1      1      2
14: 2 1      1      2
15: 1 2      1      2
16: 2 2      1      2
17: 1 3      1      2
18: 2 3      1      2
19: 1 1      2      2
20: 2 1      2      2
21: 1 2      2      2
22: 2 2      2      2
23: 1 3      2      2
24: 2 3      2      2
25: 1 1      1      3
26: 2 1      1      3
27: 1 2      1      3
28: 2 2      1      3
29: 1 3      1      3
30: 2 3      1      3
31: 1 1      2      3
32: 2 1      2      3
33: 1 2      2      3
34: 2 2      2      3
35: 1 3      2      3
36: 2 3      2      3
```

Note that a workaround where the prime matrix is constructed directly without Vmat is not useful in my context.  The manipulation must be done on Vmat directly. It was pruned and to do the full power set directly on the actual data will result in a memory error and is also clunky as there are a large number of columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `tidyverse` approach:

```
Vmat1 = data.frame(expand.grid(c(list(d = 1:2, w = 1:3))))

library(tidyverse)

Vmat1 %>%
  mutate(list(.)) %>%       # for every row add the same whole dataframe as a list
  unnest() %>%              # unnest the nested new column
  setNames(gsub("1", "prime", names(.)))  # update names
```

This will solve the issue with the names

```
Vmat1 = data.frame(expand.grid(c(list(d = 1:2, w = 1:3))))
Vmat2 = Vmat1
names(Vmat2) = paste0(names(Vmat1), "prime")

library(tidyverse)

Vmat1 %>%
  mutate(list(d=Vmat2)) %>%   # for every row add the same dataframe (updated names) as a list
  unnest()                    # unnest the nested new column
```

Comment: Incidentally, some column names already have 1 in them, is it possible to make it so it only gsubs the ending, or it doesn't use a 1 to tack on?

Comment: Otherwise this disrupts the column names

Answer (score 1):

Here's a data.table approach that depends on recycling:

```
NewMat <- Vmat1[ , list(d=d,w=w, dprime=rep(d, each=6), wprime=rep(w, each=6))]

> str(NewMat)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  36 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ d     : int  1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 ...
 $ w     : int  1 1 2 2 3 3 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ dprime: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ wprime: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

To generalize substitute nrow(Vmat1) for the 6's